# Convert MB nunber to GB or TB

Tags: php

In my code I am outputting a number from a database, the number is in MB.

So for example I am getting the HDD size and free space.

Looks like this:

```
C: CAP 1141919
C: FREE 487205
```

What I am trying to do is convert those number to either TB or GB

The output would look like:

```
C: CAP 1.141919TB
C: FREE 487.205GB
```

Further more I want to cut the input down to two decimal places.

```
C: CAP 1.14TB
C: FREE 487.20GB
```

I have tried a couple different functions however most of them want the number in bytes, which I did find a way to convert the number from MB to B then to GB but I ran into a problem with the TB, also im sure there is a way to do this in one step.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how many megabytes in gigabyte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function convert($size)
{
     $filesizename = array(" MB", " GB", " TB");
     $size = round($size/pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2) . $filesizename[$i]; 
     return $size; 
}

 $test = convert(4000);
  echo $test; //produces 3.91 GB
```

Answer (score 0):

another variant:

```
function convertMB($mb) {
    $mb = floatval($mb) / 1024.0;
    return ($mb < 1024) ? (number_format($mb, 2).'GB') : (number_format($mb / 1024.0, 2).'TB');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set decimal points by number_format function:

```
$number = number_format($number, 2); // 2 is decimal points
```